# Backup Class Not Showing in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo Reference

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, smo

I want to add Backup and Restore Functionality in C# Windows Form Application. for this i inserted

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo reference in my code.. but I can't see the Backup and Restore classes in this reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer by my self. and that is

for using Backup and restore class of SMO we need to 5 reffereces.

Go to Your Application and Right Click on References folder and select Add Reference.

Now Go to "Browse" Tab and browse the following path- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies`

Now Select the following dlls

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

I have added only this (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll) reference first but for Backup and Restore classes we also need this (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll) reference