# backup database with SMO method

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want to get backup from database with SMO method, below is my code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

Backup backupdb = new Backup();
                        backupdb.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                        backupdb.Database = "PCPdb";
                        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog savefd = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
                        savefd.Filter = "Backup File (*.Bak)|*.Bak";
                        savefd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
                        Nullable<bool> result = savefd.ShowDialog();
                        if (result == true)
                        {
                            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(savefd.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                            backupdb.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                            backupdb.SqlBackup(srvr);
                           //MessageBox.Show("Backup Database Successfully");
```

but i get the exception like this in line " `**backupdb.SqlBackup(srvr);**`"
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll

Comment: Make sure you have all the references added correctly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584494/6741868) will help you determine which are needed.

Comment: Can you provide exception details & stack trace? Which platform in use & have you installed SMO components properly?

Comment: Visual studio 2013, and WPF application, also i dont think i have installed SMO components properly, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i add these references: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll,Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll

Comment: the inner exception is: {"Failed to connect to server ."}

Comment: problem solved byb adding this at the first of my function: SqlConnection.ClearAllPools(); thanks to everyone